# How to reduce 30 amps to 5

Tags: transformer, amperage, ionization

I recently bought a Transformer so that I can make an ionic lifter but it has a max 30 amp output and I’m sure that is way too much for what I need plus Since I have this plugged straight into the wall I’ll definitely need an ac to dc rectifier which at most goes to about 5 amps So my question is how can I reduce the output amps so that I don’t mess up this rectifier as soon as I get it.

Btw the transformer is a 3000W YaeCCC Auto Transformer

Comment: attach a load that only requires 5A or less

Comment: Max current is the max any load can safely pull. The transformer will only output whatever power the load draws... This is I=V/R

Answer (score -3):

Inrush Current Limiters (ICL) | Circuit Protection | DigiKey
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/circuit.../inrush-current-limiters-icl/1... 
CL, Active, 10 Ohms, ±25%, 5A, 180 mOhms, 0.770" (19.56mm), 0.328" (8.33mm), UL. SL22 2R515 Datasheet, SL22 2R515 - Ametherm, 570-1047-ND.

Comment: Tom, the OP is clearly struggling with basic theory. If you are recommending a device then you need to explain why you think this is a good solution to "reduce the output amps" and where it would be wired into the transformer. In any case, the link is broken.